# Django Form: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms

Getting an error: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_new' not found. 'post_new' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

my form in base.html:

```
> <form action="{% url 'post_new' %}" method="post">
>     {% csrf_token %}
>     Name:<br>
>     <input type="text" name="name"><br>
>     Text:<br>
>     <input type="text" name="text">
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
```

views.py:

```
def post_new(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    name = request.POST['name']
    print(name)
    return render(request, 'blog/base.html', {'posts': posts})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.base),
    url(r'^post_new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

Comment: what happens if you replace `action="{% url 'post_new' %}"` with `action="."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you might have an app in your Django project called `blog`. Assuming this is the case, you need to use namespaces. In your main `urls.py` file, you should have something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
]
```

You can keep the `urlpatterns` the same in the `urls.py` under your `blog` app. With this namespace set you can reference the `post_new` view in your templates by doing the following:

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:post_new' %}" method="post">
```

This looks for the view called `post_new` in the `blog` app.